# Given $\beta \gt 4$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k}{n\choose{k}}{n\choose{k-1}} \over{\beta^{n}}}} = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, binomial-coefficients

I'm having trouble with a proof:

> Let $a_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{k{n\choose{k}}{n \choose{k-1}}}$. Given $\beta \gt 4$, show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{a_{n}}{\beta^{n}}} = 0$

I'm struggling to find an approach to this question due to the double binomial in the summation. Could anyone give me a hint or tip on how to start?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: *Hint.* Let $M_n=\max_{0\leq k\leq n}\binom{n}{k}$ and argue that $$\frac{2^n}{n+1}\leq M_n\leq 2^n$$ using the binomial theorem $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$. Then, if $k_n$ is such that $M_n=\binom{n}{k_n}$, can you verify that $$M_n^2\leq (k_n+1)\binom{n}{k_n+1}\binom{n}{k_n}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\leq n M_n^2$$ ?

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you, I managed to get it using your tip.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you as well. The solution you sent uses an identity I haven't seen yet, so I'm sure it will help me in the future.

Comment: You are welcome. [Search on Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7Bn%5Cchoose%7Bk%7D%7D%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%7Bk-1%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1) might also help you in the future [;-)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)